# How to hide the title bar on the Mac Catalyst version of my MAUI program?

Tags: .net, macos, maui, titlebar, mac-catalyst

I am just getting into .NET and MAUI, and I wanted to remove the titlebar on [this test app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8vsa.jpg). I am not talking about the toolbar created by MAUI (in light grey), but rather the window title bar set my UIKit. [This Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/mac_catalyst/removing_the_title_bar_in_your_mac_app_built_with_mac_catalyst) page shows what I want to do.

I have tried changing the title bar visibility in the `program.cs` inside the MacCatalyst folder (as was suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/891946/maui-tilebar-color-change) for a slightly unrelated problem), and I do have access to the `UIKit.UITitleBar` class (and can access its visibility state with the `UIKit.UITitlebarTitleVisibility` enum), but I have not found a way to turn to change this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `CreateWindow` method in your App class to create a Window, I created a new project to test on Mac, you can refer to the following code:

```
using UIKit;

namespace MauiAppDemo;

public partial class App : Application

{    
  public App()    
  {        
    InitializeComponent();        
    //MainPage = new AppShell();             
  }

  protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)    
  {
    var window = new Window();        
    window.HandlerChanged += windowHandlerChanged;        
    var rootPage = new MainPage();        
    window.Page = rootPage;        
    return window;    
  }

  private void windowHandlerChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)    
  {        
    var win = sender as Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Window;        
    var uiWin = win.Handler.PlatformView as UIWindow;        
    if (uiWin != null)        
    {            
        uiWin.WindowScene.Titlebar.TitleVisibility = UITitlebarTitleVisibility.Hidden;        
    }   
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. With appropriate #if-directives, this can even be used for cross platform apps (run the original MainPage declaration on Android, iOS, and Windows, and only run the override methods on MacCatalyst) - just for future reference if anyone else needs it.